# Firebase Authentication Access Token failed, Token created with auth custom token

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Why created token authentication error?
( NodeJs 10, database realtime read, write, run on localMacOs)
-test in local
-test as google cloud function (set authentication token)

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require('./...json');
const uid = '...';

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: '...',
});

const additionalClaims = {
  premiumAccount: true,
};

console.log('token');
admin
  .auth()
  .createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims)
  .then((token) => {
    console.log(`token : ${token}`);
    admin
      .auth()
      .verifyIdToken(token)
      .then((decodedToken) => {
        console.log(decodedToken);
        return true;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        return true;
      });

    return true;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`error : ${err}`);
    return true;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom tokens are not ID tokens. Passing a custom token to `verifyIdToken()` is an error. See Firebase documentation for examples on how to exchange a custom token for an ID token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients